# How can I manage simultaneous activities in Android?

Tags: android

How can I improve the performance of simultaneous processes with regard to execution time and memory consumption in Android?

Comment: Please consider adding a few hundred more words to explain what it is you are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Android activities are managed by using tintent. Here is the sample code how you can create and use Intent,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Mainactivity.this, secondactivity .class)
start activity(intent);
```

By this you will be able to move from one to the other activity.